# No Terminal Library Found when Compiling Vim

Tags: command-line, compiling, vim

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.

I'm trying to a get a particular plugin for vim working and it requires that vim has ruby support enabled (the plugin is command-t).

People tell me that I must go into my vim directory and run

```
./configure --enable-rubyinterp
```

When i do this i get the following error:

```
    no terminal library found
checking for tgetent()... configure: error: NOT FOUND!
      You need to install a terminal library; for example ncurses.
      Or specify the name of the library with --with-tlib.
```

Now I’ve checked and ncurses-base is installed.

What do I need to do?

Comment: I think you should install a `ncurses-dev` library

Comment: could you provide the contents of `src/auto/config.log`

Comment: thank you epsilon, that solved it. Could you make that into answer so i can give you credit

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I think you should install a `ncurses-dev` library.

you can do so by running `sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev`

Comment: I'm running ubuntu 16.10 and couldn't find a package "ncurses-dev" .  I finally found that installing libtinfo-dev did the trick.

Comment: on ubuntu 16.04:  `sudo apt-get install ncurses-dev`

Comment: Latest apt repositories select `libncurses5-dev` over `ncurses-dev`

Comment: on CentOS: `sudo yum install ncurses-devel` If fixed this `checking for working terminal libraries... Cannot find terminal libraries - configure failed`

Answer (score 19):

Run `sudo apt-get build-dep vim` to install all the packages that was used to build the vim package from the repositories.

Comment: + 1 for the build-dep command

Answer (score 16):

if you *don't* have sudo access, the solution is as follows:

download the latest (or whichever) release of `ncurses` from http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/ncurses/

run these bash commands:

```
mkdir ~/usr/local
cd <path_to_ncurses>
tar xzvf <ncurses>.tar.gz # change the tar command if it is not a tar.gz
cd <ncurses>
./configure --prefix=$HOME/usr/local
make
make install
cd <path_to_vim>
LDFLAGS=-L$HOME/usr/local/lib ./configure # then add any options e.g. --prefix=$HOME/usr/local
make
make install
```

And there you go. It's not often that people don't have sudo access to a machine, but this was my case, and this thread didn't provide the information I needed :) Now it does

Comment: In my case, the above step is still not good enough. I need to add `$HOME/usr/local/lib` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running ubuntu 16.10 and couldn't get vim 8.0 to compile.  Googling the issue told me to install a package `ncurses-dev` but I couldn't find that package. I finally found that installing package `libtinfo-dev` did the trick and I was able to compile vim.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, I did `sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev`.

I was on Ubuntu 14.04. It worked.

Comment: Does it add anything to the accepted answer?

Comment: # sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libncurses5-dev is already the newest version (6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1).
libncursesw5-dev is already the newest version (6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 40 not upgraded.
............................still getting err : /usr/bin/ld: help.o: undefined reference to symbol 'delwin@@NCURSES_5.0.19991023'

Comment: //usr/local/lib/libncurses.so.5: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:18: recipe for target 'omnitty' failed
make: *** [omnitty] Error 1